# force:mdapi:convert duplicate files

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode, mdapi

I've been trying to commit to having version control in our org, and I have been using DX to do so. My biggest complaint right now is that I end up having a ton of .dup files. And I don't know of the best way to compare and merge them. Here are the steps that I take to get the information:

1. Create an unmanaged project in SF
2. sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./mdapipkg -u  -p
3. sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir ./mdapipkg/

I also thought it would be a good idea to get the metadata for my production org. So here are the steps I take for that repo:

1. get package.xml from https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/
2. sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdapipkg/ -u Production -k ./package.xml
3. sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir ./mdapipkg/

And the same thing happens with both scenarios. I end up with plenty of .dup files that I have to manually copy paste or delete. What is the best way to handle this? I am using Visual Studio Code.

As a side note, when I pull from production, I have to delete the emailservices and reports folder from the extracted folder within mdapipkg. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use version control on the metadata format.  I suggest sticking to the new DX source format, and then use `force:mdapi` commands when you are trying to deploy to production.  This should avoid the .dup files problem, and using the DX source format in your projects is the new path forward in code development and iteration.

Anytime you create a SFDX project (whether through the command line or using VS Code SFDX UI specific commands), it'll automatically setup the DX source folder structure, and the subsequent SFDX commands to create classes, components, etc will also leverage the new format.

Comment: Yeah, that is the goal. How do I get DX to pull the changes I have made? I don't really understand what you mean by DX source format. I'd like to not just have to copy and paste the changes.